# Ubuntu 16.04 stuck in boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot

My Ubuntu 16.04 is getting stuck, it bypasses the login screen and logs in as guest on boot.

I can reboot and go to GRUB menu and I can access recovery mode and root.

Running `fsck` returns

```
/dev/sda6 is mounted. e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

If it helps `systemctl --failed` gives

```
systemd-modules-load.service
as loaded with ACTIVE failed and SUB failed.
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Note that Ubuntu posts are a special case. If your question applies to Ubuntu only, or you're looking for answers that are Ubuntu-specific, you should post it on the Ask Ubuntu Stack Exchange site.

Comment: They sent me here, unfortunately.

Comment: @Rob - Ubuntu 16.x is "no longer supported" on AU

Comment: Have you tried unmounting `/dev/sda6` before running `fsck`?

Comment: @Greenonline I'm only quoting the Help Center here. It's a sad state of affairs again for Linux that an Ubuntu platform doesn't support Ubuntu.

Comment: @Rob - I agree wholeheartedly... also why aren't the older questions related to unsupported versions then deleted..? IMHO, the whole premise behind AU is rather confused, inconsistent and poorly thought out, hence why I prefer to hang out here.

Answer (score 0):

When you're booting into `recovery mode` it sounds like `/dev/sda6` is your root partition or another partition that's already mounted.

I think that your best bet will be to copy a Ubuntu 16.04 Live disk onto a USB stick, and boot from the USB stick.

Once you've booted from the USB stick use whichever disk tools you prefer to check the disk assuming that you really have a disk problem.

I suspect that your disk may be fine though. If you were having disk problems, you would probably not be getting logged in as anyone on boot.

Assuming that when you're auto logged in as a guest to the system that you're getting the Ubuntu desktop, I think you can go into

System Settings > User Accounts > click the "Unlock" at the top and then disable "Automatic Login"

[image]

Comment: I'm now thinking that /dev/sda6 is the root partition and it's accidentally become full due to a file being accidentally assigned to download to it instead of the external USB. How can I access the drive from the guest session?

Comment: Assuming that by "guest session" you mean logged into the guest user account on a desktop session, then just open a terminal and `sudo -s` for root access. If by "guest session" you mean when you're booting off of a USB disk, you just mount the drive to access it... `mount /dev/sda6 /mnt`... Then `cd /mnt/home/guest/Downloads` or something like that and clear out the extra files.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, that will be very useful in future, after fiddling about with recovery mode I actually found I could just switch user in the menu in the guest session, and was sorted.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, that will be very useful in future, after fiddling about with recovery mode I actually found I could just switch user in the menu in the guest session, and was sorted.